# What methods are proposed for storing cryogenic fuels (esp. hydrogen) in space for months or years?

Tags: mars, propulsion, fuel, thermal, cryogenics

Current Launch vehicles and upper stages must only keep their fuels for minutes or hours, so they are only insulated to keep boiloff to a few % per day - I've seen 21% per day quoted for Centaur on coasts to GEO.

For proposed "fuel depots" or Mars missions, hydrogen (and oxygen) must be kept liquid for years with minimal losses, is this achievable purely with insulation and sun shading or are refrigeration methods being considered?

Comment: Related, possibly a duplicate https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2848/how-long-is-it-feasible-to-store-cryogenic-fuels

Comment: Oh, there's some useful stuff there actually, thanks.

I still think it's worth seeing if there's any new answers

Comment: related but different but interesting but (currently) unanswered: [How will Robotic Refueling Mission-3's liquid methane tank remain full for six months without any boil off?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32546/12102)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NASA had a [zero boil-off tank](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/research/experiments/1270.html) on the ISS for some time, but they haven't updated much of that page unfortunately. With [CRS-16](https://sspd.gsfc.nasa.gov/RRM3.html) they sent the third in a series of robotic missions to the ISS that is supposed to maintain cryogenic fluid for six months, as well as transfer said cryogenic fluids in microgravity. That mission launched in early December, so we should hear more later this year. Back as far as [2012](https://www.nasa.gov/pdf/743213main_CPST_Tech_Maturation.pdf) TRL of 4-6 for storage of hydrolox had been accomplished (you can find what TRL means [here](https://www.nasa.gov/directorates/heo/scan/engineering/technology/txt_accordion1.html)), with a TRL of 6 being a fully functional prototype.

For more generalized proposals, there was one from [ULA in 2008](https://www.ulalaunch.com/docs/default-source/extended-duration/a-practical-affordable-cryogenic-propellant-depot-based-on-ula's-flight-experience.pdf), a somewhat similar one from a group [not too much later](https://www.ulalaunch.com/docs/default-source/extended-duration/propellant-depots-2009.pdf), some tangential details in relation to a [single depot being used for multiple missions](https://selenianboondocks.com/2018/09/aas-paper-review-raan-agnostic-3-burn-departure-methodology-for-deep-space-missions-from-leo-depots-part-2-of-2/), and this [large 2011 NASA proposal that got almost no mention in the public sphere](http://images.spaceref.com/news/2011/21.jul2011.vxs.pdf). In general it seems for long-term storage most proposals are assuming some sort of active cooling over passive protection.

Comment: any cryo-thoughts here? [How will Robotic Refueling Mission-3's liquid methane tank remain full for six months without any boil off?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32546/12102)

Comment: If it's anything like RRM-1, then [thermal blankets](https://earth.esa.int/web/eoportal/satellite-missions/i/iss-rrm) are the most specific information I've been able to find. I'm going to keep an eye out because I'm really curious, perhaps once its mission is complete someone will release a paper with more technical information.