# What is the record for LOX staying liquid in space?

Tags: record, cryogenics, lox

Liquid oxygen can be used for breathing, for fuel cells, and as an oxidizer for propulsion.  However, it is cryogenic, and will slowly boil off in storage, even in a spacecraft.  **What is the longest amount of time that LOX has been known to stay liquid in space?**  I am particularly looking for the duration between the time of launch and the time at which the remaining liquid amount is no longer considered adequate for its intended purpose (i.e. complete boil-off is not necessary).

[Another question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/2848/26446) asks about the record for cryogenic fuels.  This question differs because I am asking about *all* uses of LOX -- not just as propellant.  (For example, space stations should be considered here but not there.)  Also, the only answer to that question addresses LH2 but not LOX.

Comment: For liquid methane, it may be four months https://space.stackexchange.com/a/35620/6944 The same technology would probably work for LOX.

Comment: The oxygen for the fuel cells of the Apollo Service Module was stored as supercritical fluid, not as liquid oxygen. The supercritical fluid could exist under high pressure (above 50.4 bar) at temperatures above the boiling point of LOX.

Comment: The Spitzer Space Telescope stored liquid helium for detector cooling from August 2003 to Mai 2009. The boiling point of helium is lower than that of hydrogen and oxygen.

Comment: This question should be reworded.  If you toss a container of LOX out there, add a reliable sun-shield to it,  there is no heat source and it'll stay cold forever.   If you keep the container in a spacestation and hook it up to a heat pump, it'll stay cold forever.   What is the situation you want to know about?